# filtering with collect in common lisp loop macro

Tags: loops, common-lisp, list-comprehension

I am trying to filter a list using the loop macro. If I do

```
(loop for x in (list 1 2 3 4) collect x)
```

I just get the same list back, which makes sense. However, I would like to do something like

```
(loop for x in (list 1 2 3 4) collect x if (evenp x))
```

and get `(2 4)` back, but that's not legal. For some reason, I can't find the appropriate syntax for this on other documentation. Is this possible?

Comment: "I can't find the appropriate syntax for this on other documentation."  The HyperSpec is pretty reasonable documentation.  The entry for [**loop**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_loop.htm) includes a grammar, and the relevant production is `conditional::= {if | when | unless} form selectable-clause {and selectable-clause}*  
               [else selectable-clause {and selectable-clause}*]  
               [end] `.  You just need to change the order to **if (evenp x) collect x** (though if you're not using **else**, then **when** would be more idiomatic).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct syntax is

```
(loop for x in (list ...) when (evenp x) collect x)
```

Comment: Alternatively `(loop for x in (list ...) if (evenp x) collect x)`.